# Can $\le$ be used insted of < in the definition of continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

A common definition of a continuous map $T:M_1\to M_2$ is that for every $x\in M_1$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for all $y$ in $M_1$
$$d_1(x,y)<\delta \implies d_2(T(x),T(y))<\varepsilon,$$
i.e. we use a strict inequality. Now in a proof it reads that $T$ is continuous if for every $x\in M_1$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$\|Tx-Ty\|\le\varepsilon\ \mbox{for all $y$ in $M_1$ satisfying } \|x-y\|\le \delta.$$
Here the norm is given by the metric. Is it correct to use $\le$ instead of the strict inequality <, and can one somehow prove the equality of these definitions? Or is this obviously the same condition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *todo lo que se diga para espacios topológicos vale para espacios métricos *

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ two topological spaces then for the definition of continuity
there is an equivalence:

**A map $f: X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for each closed set $A$ in $Y$ we have $f^{-1}A$ is closed in $X$.**

So, an answer to your question is included.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: @Alexander, the best of all is that the proof of this continuity's property is pretty easy!

Comment: Much more elegant than mine!

Comment: XD but not! 'cuz i used topology and you metric spaces XD

Comment: @par, just you see this: epsilon-delta are to  scare engineers but open-closed sets to scare physicist and one or two mathematicians

Comment: As you say,  your argument has two gaps: 1. It uses without proof the fact that $f : M_1 \to M_2$ is $\epsilon$-$\delta$-$<$-continuous iff preimages of open sets are open. This is easy to prove, but it requires to introduce the concept of open sets in metric spaces. 2. It seems to use without proof the fact that $f : M_1 \to M_2$ is $\epsilon$-$\delta$-$\le$-continuous iff preimages of closed sets are closed.  I am not sure whether this is so easy as 1.

Comment: ok, take as it sounds a challenge

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous at $x\in X$ in the
usual sense.
That is,
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0\colon\exists\delta>0\colon\forall x^{\prime}\in X\colon d_{X}\left(x,x^{\prime}\right)<\delta\Rightarrow d_{Y}\left(f\left(x\right),f\left(x^{\prime}\right)\right)<\varepsilon.
$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta$ s.t. for all $x^{\prime}\in X$,
$d_{X}\left(x,x^{\prime}\right)<\delta$ implies $d_{Y}\left(f\left(x\right),f\left(x^{\prime}\right)\right)<\varepsilon\leq\varepsilon$.
Take $\delta^{\prime}\equiv\delta-\alpha$ for some $0<\alpha<\delta$.

Suppose now that $f$ is continuous at $x$ in the ``exotic'' sense.
That is,
$$
\forall\varepsilon>0\colon\exists\delta>0\colon\forall x^{\prime}\in X\colon d_{X}\left(x,x^{\prime}\right)\leq\delta\Rightarrow d_{Y}\left(f\left(x\right),f\left(x^{\prime}\right)\right)\leq\varepsilon.
$$
Let $\beta>0$ and $\varepsilon-\beta>0$. Then there exists $\delta$
s.t. for all $x^{\prime}\in X$, $d_{X}\left(x,x^{\prime}\right)<\delta\leq\delta$
implies $d_{X}\left(f\left(x\right),f\left(x^{\prime}\right)\right)\leq\varepsilon-\beta<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in the previous answers, you can use either the definition with all inequalities strict ($\lt$) or either the definition with all inequalities "less or equal" ($\leq$).

What you cannot do is using $\leq$ for the $\delta$ and the $\lt$ for $\epsilon$ (you cannot either use $\lt$ for $\delta$ and $\leq$ for $\epsilon$).

The reason is, as janmarqz said, that we have continuity of a function if the preimage of every closed set is a closed set OR if the preimage of every open set is an open.

One can not mix the two...

Comment: Both the things that you claim aren't possible can actually be done. Call $P(f,x,\star,\diamond)$ predicate $$P(f,x,\star,\diamond)\equiv\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,\forall y,(\lVert x-y\rVert\star\delta\Rightarrow \lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert\diamond\varepsilon)$$For a function $f:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ and a pont $x\in\Bbb R^m$, the following are equivalent: 1) $P(f,x,<,<)$; 2) $P(f,x,\le,<)$; 3) $P(f,x,<,\le)$; 4) $P(f,x,\le,\le)$. Same for functions beteen metric spaces.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know about it. Do you have some book / website (or just reference) where I can learn more about what you're saying ?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the preimage of an open by this function is a closed ? And hence, violate the topological definition of continuity ?

Comment: No, I don't have a reference, it's generally just a trick like: "you have a $\delta_\varepsilon$ from one formulation, take $\delta'_\varepsilon:=\frac{\delta_{\varepsilon/2}}2$ for the other". No, there is nothing in these formulations about closed preimages of open sets.

Comment: The topological counterpart, if you want, is that given some $x\in (X,\tau)$, a fundamental system of neighbourhoods $\mathcal N_x$ for $x$ and a fundamental system of neighbourhoods $\mathcal M_{f(x)}$ for $f(x)$, $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for all $M\in\mathcal M_{f(x)}$ there is some $N\in\mathcal N_x$ such that $f^{-1}[M]\supseteq N$.