# Shrinking rectangles and subaditivity of Lesbesgue outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The measure theory [notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes.pdf) (John K. Hunter) states:

**Definition 2.1**

A $n$-dimensional closed rectangle is a subset $R \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that

$$R = [a_{1}, b_{1}] \times [a_{2}, b_{2}] \times \cdots \times [a_{2}, b_{2}]$$

where $-\infty \lt a_{i} \le b_{i} \lt \infty$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

Denote collection of all $n$-dimensional rectangles as $\mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Volume of $R$ is:

$$\mu(R) = (b_{1} - a_{1})(b_{2} - a_{2})\cdots(b_{n} - a_{n})$$

We also consider empty set as a rectangle with $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

Then, $R \mapsto \mu(R)$ defines a map $\mu : \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$.

---

**Definition 2.2**

The outer Lesbesgue measure $\mu^{*}(E)$ of a subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is

$$\mu^{*}(E) = \inf \left \lbrace \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{i}) : E \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} R_{i}, R_{i} \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \right \rbrace$$

where the infinum is taken over all countable collections of rectangles whose union contains $E$.

.

---

**Question**

In proof of 2.4, the notes states:

Consider the case that $\mu^{*}(E_{i})$ is finite for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

For all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a countable covering $\lbrace R_{ij} : j \in {N} \rbrace$ of $E_{i} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by rectangles $R_{ij}$ such that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{ij}) \le \mu^{*}(E_{i}) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{i}}, \qquad E_{i} \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} R_{ij}$$

I can prove $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{ij}) \lt \mu^{*}(E_{i})$ by a theorem about infimum (but not $\le$). How to show the two sides can be equal?

I think the proof should show the two sides can be equal in some case because a later proof (proposition) shows the $\ge$ case. Together the two cases show $\mu^{*}(R) = \mu(R)$.

---

I see the same thing in the proof here (equation 2 and 3): http://mathonline.wikidot.com/countable-subadditivity-of-the-lebesgue-outer-measure

---

**Attempt to justify**

Consider the one dimensional case.

$$\mu^{*}(E_{i}) = \inf \left \lbrace \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{i}) : E_{i} \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} R_{i}, R_{i} \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}) \right \rbrace$$

---

Theorem 2.19 in introduction to real analysis [notes](http://www.math.louisville.edu/~lee/RealAnalysis/) (Lee Larson) states:

For $\mathbb{F}$ be an ordered field, $A \subset \mathbb{F}$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$, we have:

$\alpha$ is the infimum (or greatest lower bound) of $A$ iff:

- $(-\infty, \alpha) \cap A = \emptyset$, and
- $\forall \varepsilon' > 0: [\alpha, \alpha + \varepsilon') \cap A \ne \emptyset$

---

Here,

- the ordered field $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$,
- the subset $A \subset \mathbb{F}$ is $\left \lbrace \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{i}) : E_{i} \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} R_{i}, R_{i} \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}) \right \rbrace$,
- the infimum is $\alpha = \mu^{*}(E_{i})$, and
- $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon / 2^{i}$.

Therefore, $\forall \varepsilon' > 0: [\alpha,  \alpha + \varepsilon') \cap A \ne \emptyset$.

Then, 
$$\forall \varepsilon' > 0: [\alpha,  \alpha + \varepsilon') \cap \left \lbrace \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{i}) : E_{i} \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} R_{i}, R_{i} \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}) \right \rbrace \ne \emptyset$$

This implies for all $\varepsilon' > 0 $, there exists a collection $B = \lbrace R_{ij} \in \mathcal{R}(\mathbb{R}) : j \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$ such that:

- $E_{i} \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} B_{j}$, and
- $ \alpha \le \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \mu(B_{j}) \lt \alpha + \varepsilon'$

where $B_{j}$ is the *j*<sup>th</sup> element of the collection $B$.

That means:

$$ \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{ij}) \lt \mu^{*}(E_{i}) + \varepsilon / 2^{i},  \qquad E_{i} \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} R_{ij} $$

Unfortunately, it is a $\lt$ sign instead of $\le$ sign ...

Comment: $a<b$ implies $a\le b$, so your result doesn't need to be wrong. But what about the case where $E_i$ is a rectangle? Also, can you state your "theorem about infimum"?

Comment: I think the proof should show that $a$ and $b$ can actually be equal in some case. This proof should show $a \le b$. Then another proof (proposition 2.7 in the notes) shows $a \ge b$. The two parts together shows $a = b$. The "theorem about inimum" is theorem 2.19 in introduction to real analysis notes (Lee Larson) at http://math.louisville.edu/~lee/ira/IntroRealAnal.pdf

Comment: I see theorem 2.19 and I don't understand where you can replace $≤$ with $<$.  Can you add a clarification to the question regarding the application of 2.19?

Comment: Erh. If the proof doesn't show how to get the equal sign for rectangle in 1D ($\mathbb{R}$. Then, the proof can't show how to get the equal sign in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Of course, the proof does not show how to get equality for rectangles, because this is /precisely/ prop 2.7. Its up to you I guess to decide if its "important".

Comment: My mistake, I meant the other way. The way I read theorem 2.19, you /only/ get $≤$. You should not be able to get $<$.

Comment: I'm telling you that your application of theorem 2.19 of Larson's notes is wrong.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Can I know the mistakes that I made? I added my attempt to justify that step.

Comment: @CalvinKhor i can't quite get your point because the formatting is messed up. If you have the correct justification that the two sides can be equal for some epsilon. I will gladly give you the bounty.

Comment: noted, I was trying to fix the formatting but failed. When I put the exact same `LaTeX` code into the answer box, it formatted perfectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your edit, you have a completely different statement,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu(R_{i j})<\mu^{*}\left(E_{i}\right)+\varepsilon / 2^{i} $$
is not at all the same as $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu\left(R_{i j}\right)<\mu^{*}\left(E_{i}\right) $$ which is what was originally in your question.

Here, the $\le$ and $<$ statements are equivalent. A similar situation you may have encountered - [Conflicting definitions of continuity (strict or non-strict inequality)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904220/conflicting-definitions-of-continuity-strict-or-non-strict-inequality) If its true that for every $\epsilon$, then the $\le$ statement for $\epsilon/2$ will give you
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu\left(R_{i j}\right)\le \mu^{*}(E_i)+(\varepsilon/2) / 2^{i} < \mu^*(E_{i})+\varepsilon / 2^i.
$$

If you followed the proof all the way to the end with $< \dots + \epsilon$, when using the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, you again get $\le$, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: @hamsteronwheels (a) No, this equality is wrong. Note that the collection $R_{ij}$ depends on $\epsilon$. (b) Are you talking about $\mathbb R$ or a rectangle $R$? You don't need 2.7 to show $\mu^*(\mathbb R)=\infty$ (and I dont think $\mu(\mathbb R)$ is defined at this point)

Comment: Do you mean that since epsilon is an arbitrary positive number, the proof in the notes show $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu(\mathcal{R}_{ij})=\mu^{*}(E_{i})$? I think I get that. It is exercise 2.12 in Lee Larson's notes. This seems to be a simpler route to show $\mu^{*}(\mathcal{R})=\mu(\mathcal{R})$ without requiring proposition 2.7. Somehow, instead of following this route, they prove the ≥ case later in proposition 2.7 and then conclude the two parts together show $\mu^{*}(\mathcal{R})=\mu(\mathcal{R})$. $\mathcal{R}$ means a n-dimensional rectangle. Sorry for formatting mistake.

Comment: @hamsteronwheels (a) No, if there is an $R_{ij}$ in the equation, then there is an $\epsilon$ somewhere. The inequality without $\epsilon$ cannot mention $R_{ij}$. (b) Exercise 2.12 requires a two-sided inequality $|x|  < \epsilon$. Here we only have the one-sided inequality $a \le b + \epsilon$. (or $a < b + \epsilon$, same thing.) The result is only an inequality, not an equality. You cannot just delete the proof of prop 2.7

Comment: That makes everything clear to me now. Thanks a lot for explaining this to me.

Comment: @hamsteronwheels glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $E = E_1 = [a,b] \times [c,d]$ be a finite rectangle.  *A* countable (finite, even) covering of $E_1$ by rectangles is 
$$  R = \left\{ [a,b]\times \left[c,d+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2^i(b-a)}\right]\right\}  \text{.}  $$
It should be evident that this gives the equality you ask about.